# Localisation issue while dynamically loading the WPF DLLs using MEF

Tags: localization, mef

I am trying to dynamically load DLLs and I am facing the following issues:

1. The Resources in the dynamically loaded DLLs are not working. It is picking the neutral culture which is English, and no other .resx files are getting called.
2. I am unable to call a WCF service in the dynamically loaded DLLs.

For 2) I have a work around but for 1) I am still stuck.

The technology i am using is. Net 4.0(with MEF)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternate solution for 1).
It was my mistake only, the resources DLLs were being picked from the wrong path.

Comment: Could you maybe shared a snippet of your solution? I am facing a similar problem and would be of great help.