# Getting localized resources from MEF modules

Tags: c#, .net, localization, internationalization, mef

I have a library project (SamplePlugin) that is meant to be used as an MEF module and loaded at runtime. Recently, I decided to support internationalization. To that end, I created Properties/Resource.resx and respective Properties/Resource.xx-yy.resx for each supported locale. I then added string resources with locale specific translations to each resource file. However at runtime, I cannot seem to get the culture-correct resource. Here is the relavent code:

Loading the module:

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo("Plugins/");
var dlls = di.GetFileSystemInfos("*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();

foreach (var fi in dlls)
{
    var ac = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.LoadFile(fi.FullName));
    catalog.Catalogs.Add(ac);
}

CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
container.ComposeParts(this);
```

Method inside of MEF module (SamplePlugin):

```
string GetFrenchString()
{
    var resourceManager = new ResourceManager(
        "SamplePlugin.Properties.Resources", 
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
    return (string)resourceManager.GetObject("SampleText", culture);
}
```

File structure of the compiled application:

```
app.exe
Plugins/SamplePlugin/SamplePlugin.dll
Plugins/SamplePlugin/zh-CN/SamplePlugin.resources.dll
Plugins/SamplePlugin/de-DE/SamplePlugin.resources.dll
Plugins/SamplePlugin/fr-FR/SamplePlugin.resources.dll
...
```

When I run `GetFrenchString()` I get `"Sample Text"` (from resource.resx) instead of `"exemple de texte"` (from resource.fr-FR.resx). I actually found similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802234/localisation-issue-while-dynamically-loading-the-wpf-dlls-using-mef) but the poster answered his own question and provided very little detail in both his question and answer.

Additional details:

The access modifiers of all my resource files are "public"

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: I have the same problem. Mine is a plugin with [Export].